# str.split by regex (complex pattern)

Tags: python, regex, split, header, fasta

How do I split the ID from annotation by using regex in the data frame below?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"header":["SS50377_28860 All-trans-retinol 13,14-reductase"]})
```

So the columns supposed to be like this:

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame({"id":"SS50377_28860","header":["All-trans-retinol 13,14-reductase"]})
```

The following code doesn't work properly.

```
df.join(df["header"].str.split(r'\d+', 0, expand=True))
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split with one or more whitespaces between a digit and a letter:

```py
df[['id','header']] = df['header'].str.split(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=[A-Z])', n=1, expand=True)
```

Or, you may capture the ID pattern into one group and the rest into another:

```py
df[['id', 'header']] = df['header'].str.extract(r'^([A-Z0-9]+_[A-Z0-9]+)\s+(.*)', expand=True)
```

Or, you may simply `Series.str.split` with the first whitespace chunk:

```py
df[['id', 'header']] = df['header'].str.split("\s+", n=1, expand=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                              header             id
0  All-trans-retinol 13,14-reductase  SS50377_28860
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=\d)\s+(?=[A-Z])` - matches one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) that are immediately preceded with a digit (`(?<=\d)`) and immediately followed with an uppercase ASCII letter (`[A-Z]`)
- `^([A-Z0-9]+_[A-Z0-9]+)\s+(.*)` - matches start of string (`^`), then captures one or more uppercase ASCII letters or digits, `_` and again one or more uppercase ASCII letters or digits into Group 1 (Column "id") and then matches one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) and then captures the rest of the line into Group 2 (with `(.*)`).

Whichever solution you choose depends on how varied your input is and how much validation you want to apply here.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I love the last option. It was quite easy and practical.